# Expected value of 2 Normal variables

Tags: exponential-function, normal-distribution, expectation

What would be the expected value of:
$$
E[e^{aX-Y}]\\$$ X, Y~Normal(mu, sigma^2)

Right now I have:

$$ e^{(aE[X]-E[Y]+1/2[a^2Var[X]-Var[Y]-2aCov(X,Y)])} $$

Is it correct?

Comment: No.  Generally $\mathsf E(e^{g(X,Y)})\neq e^{\mathsf E(g(X,Y))}$.  Look up [moment generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function).

Comment: Is there nothing in the text of the problem about the independence of these random variables?

Comment: The covariance term is taking care of independence/ or lack of independende...